# Computing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-An}sin(Bn)}{n}$, where $A,B$ are constants.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, summation

**Problem**

Compute: $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-An}\sin(Bn)}{n}$$

My attempt, let
$$ I =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{-An}}{n} \left( \cos(Bn) + i \sin(Bn) \right) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{n(-A + iB)}}{n} $$

Using the series expansion,

$$ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{zx}}{x} = \log{\left( \frac{1}{1-e^{iz}} \right)} $$

we obtain

$$ I = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{n(-A + iB)}}{n} = \log{\left( \frac{1}{1-e^{i(-A + iB)}} \right)} $$

Which gives, $$ S = \Im(I) = \Im\left(  \log{\left( \frac{1}{1-e^{i(-A + iB)}} \right)} \right). $$

However, I am not sure of this answer. This series originated while doing a problem of Physics, whose solution I do not possess. Any methods to do it more precisely are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an extra $i$
$$I = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{n(-A + iB)}}{n} =-\log \left(1-e^{-A+i B}\right)$$

Expanding the complex numbers
$$\Im(I)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (B)}{e^A-\cos (B)}\right)$$
$$\Re(I)=\frac{1}{2} (A-\log (2 \cosh (A)-2 \cos (B)))$$

Comment: Yes I accidentally put an $i$ n the Taylor expansion.

Comment: How did you expand the complex numbers?